# Entitlements and recurring milestone's start time and target time

Tags: case, casemilestone, entitlements, entitlement-process

I am new to entitlements and we are trying to leverage this for our service cloud. My business requirements are as follows:

**Requirements:**
Everytime a case status is set to "Response Received" there should be a timer for 120 mins that should start from the time the status changed to Response Received.

**I have my entitlement setup as follows for my testing:**

**Milestone1**: Initial response time(**No Recurrence**)

Start time : Milestone criteria

Criteria : Status = "Open"

Timer : 120mins

**Milestone2**: Reply to Customer(**Sequential**)

Start time: Milestone criteria

Criteria: status = Response Received

Timer : 120mins.

Now I have been testing with Sequential milestones. It works the first time the case satisfies this milestone criteria but the second time status changes to Response received it is actally setting its target date as 2 hours from the previous milestones target date and not from the time the case status changed to Response Received the second time. Is there any way we can do this?

Answer (score -2):

Change the Milestone type to Independent instead of Sequential. This will help.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.entitlements_milestone_sequential_recurrence.htm&type=5

If you choose Independent Milestone Type, then it will calculate the target date from the time it met the criteria, irrespective of how many times the criteria meets on a case.

Comment: How will it help? You need to [edit] your answer to include more detail.

Comment: Added some more details. Do check it out. I think it would be helpful in your use case.